# How do I read and upload a large file to s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, fs

I'm using Node.js .10.22 and [q-fs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io)

I'm trying to upload objects to S3, which stopped working once the objects were over a certain MB size.

Besides taking up all the memory on my machine, it gives me this error

```
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
at new Buffer (buffer.js:194:21)
```

When I try to use `fs.read` on the file.

Normally, when this works, I do `s3.upload`, and put the buffer in the `Body` field.

How do I handle large objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a streaming version of the API to pipe your readable filesystem stream directly to the S3 upload http request body stream provided by the s3 module you are using. Here's an example straight from the [aws-sdk documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html)

```
var fs = require('fs');

var body = fs.createReadStream('bigfile');
var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey'}});
s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
  on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
  send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

Comment: I'm working with video files. Doing this corrupts my video and it can't be played.

Comment: But perhaps I just have to un-zip it if I want to use the file again? Nevertheless removing the `.pipe(zlib.createGzip())` stuff works.